# how to set FINDSTR result from WMIC command into variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, wmic, findstr

I'm trying to make simple (but not for me) script, which will unistall stubborn software and want to find it ID number with WMIC function and FINDSTR "filter". I'm trying it with this code:`for /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('wmic product get name,identifyingnumber | findstr /c:"SOFTWARE NAME"')do set var=%%i echo %var%` but when trying to run scritp it shows for a milisecond and then disappear. Later i want to use this result with `msiexec /x (var)` to unistall this software. What is wrong with FOR function?

Tried `wmic product get name,identifyingnumber | findstr /c:"SOFTWARE NAME"` to see if it finds right software and it works good.

Comment: `powershell get-package 'google chrome'`

Comment: `powershell uninstall-package 'google chrome'`

Answer (score 0):

You are going about the task in the wrong way!

There is no need whatsoever to involve the findstr.exe command line utility, when the WMIC.exe command line utility already has the ability to locate only names matching that pattern.

However, to demonstrate how you'd do it your way, here's a quick example to return the Identifyingnumber for Microsoft Update Health Tools.

```bash
@For /F "EOL=N Tokens=2 Delims=," %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Product Get IdentifyingNumber^, Name /Format:CSV 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /C:"Microsoft Update Health Tools"') Do @Echo %%G
```

Note how I escaped the pipe character, the comma character, and the redirection character with caret characters. *The content within the parentheses is passed to another cmd.exe instance, so those characters need to be preserved in the other instance*.

---

To do it without needing `findstr.exe`:

If you already know the exact `Name`, example, `AMD Catalyst Control Center`, you could use the 'Equal To' operator:

```bash
@For /F "EOL=N Tokens=2 Delims=," %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Product Where "Name='AMD Catalyst Control Center'" Get IdentifyingNumber^, Name /Format:CSV 2^>NUL') Do @Echo %%G
```

If you only know part of the `Name` string, for example, you know it contains the substring `Visual C++`, to capture all Microsoft Visual C++ Runtimes, you'd use the 'LIKE' operator:

```bash
@For /F "EOL=N Tokens=2 Delims=," %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Product Where "Name Like '%% Visual C++ %%'" Get IdentifyingNumber^, Name /Format:CSV 2^>NUL') Do @Echo %%G
```

The pattern here is `%`, (doubled because it is in a batch file), meaning any string of zero or more characters, a space character, the string Visual, a space character, the string C++, a space character, and then finally `%` again for any string of zero or more characters.

---

*Obviously, in all cases you could just replace `@Echo %%G` with `@%SystemRoot%\System32\msiexec.exe /x %%G /q`, to directly uninstall.*

However, if you just wanted to uninstall, Microsoft Update Heath Tools, for example, you would not need a `For` loop either:

```bash
@%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Product Where "Name='Microsoft Update Health Tools'" Call Uninstall
```